# After validation hook in validation request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

Can I attach after validation hook ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#after-validation-hook)) to my custom made request with `php artisan make:request`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override `getValidatorInstance()` method in your custom request class like this:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
   $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

   // here you can apply hook (example hook taken from documentation):

    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
       if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
          $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
       }
   });

   return $validator;
}
```